# Pop Up Print is not working in android and ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my jquery code:

```
jQuery('.print_btn').hide();
var contents = document.getElementById("print_page").innerHTML;
var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
frame1.name = "frame1";
frame1.style.position = "absolute";
frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
document.body.appendChild(frame1);
var frameDoc = (frame1.contentWindow) ? frame1.contentWindow : (frame1.contentDocument.document) ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
frameDoc.document.open();
frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
frameDoc.document.write(contents);
frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
frameDoc.document.close();
setTimeout(function () {
    frameDoc.focus();
    frameDoc.print();
    document.body.removeChild(frame1);
}, 500);
jQuery('.print_btn').show();
return false;
```

I search on google but i did not find any solution so i am posting this question.
I have a pop which is having image and a print button , i want to print the image on click on print button.
This working fine on web browser means on desktop, But it is printing whole page and pop-up image , and on i pad it is printing nothing .

Why this is happening  i don't know please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `.print()` isn't supported on Android devices. You could however use Googles cloud print API: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/gadget

Comment: What about Iphone or ipad. And yes  your answer is helpful.

Comment: `.print()` should work in the native safari browser assuming you're using iOS 4.2 or above.

Comment: In my case window.print() worked ,but iframe.contentWindow.print() not